# Google Glass Compass Sample throws exception trying to create a new card

Tags: android, google-glass

So I've got Glass, installed the GDK, cloned and compiled the Compass Sample, so far so good.  Enabled debug mode on Glass, attached via USB, showing up under adb devices, install Compass Sample APK, no problems.  I see the app display as a target on my menu, then I go to click on the menu.

Expected:

I should see the compass live card show up.

Actual:

An exception is thrown, looking in the logs here's the stacktrace:

```
01-17 19:21:50.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2734): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.android.glass.timeline.TimelineManager.getLiveCard
    at com.google.android.glass.sample.compass.CompassService.onStartCommand(CompassService.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2359)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [XE12 release notes](https://developers.google.com/glass/release-notes#xe12), `TimelineManager`'s `getLiveCard()` method has been renamed [createLiveCard()](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/timeline/TimelineManager.html#createLiveCard%28java.lang.String%29). Make sure you have the latest version of the GDK and samples.

Comment: So I upgraded to the latest GDK and it worked.

Google should check the GDK level when installing like they do for the Android SDK to prevent this kind of incompatibility.

Comment: @johnarleyburns - the checking that the Android SDK does would not help here as the Android SDK assumes forward compatibility (apps built for v11 will work on v12) - that same assumption does not hold for the developer preview GDK, but I assume will be the case when it is finalized and officially released.